# Favicon doesn't show in the browser

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

The favicon is missing when i launch my application in the browser.  Also other files like robots.txt and manifest.json.  But when I go directly to the url, for example http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico, it shows.
I'm using spring boot and react.

In the generated jar file, inside /classes/static/ the following files are present:

- index.html
- manifest.json
- favicon.ico
- robots.txt

In my WebMvcConfigurer implementation, I have the following:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/")
            .setCachePeriod(0)
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                    if (!resourcePath.equals("/")) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return location.exists() && location.isReadable() ? location : null;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the browser devtools (network (inspection) tab) when reloading the page without caches (`Contr`+`R`)? Is there a custom favicon element in the `.html` file (in a `<meta>` tag or similar)?

Comment: Also, why do you return `null` in the `getResource` method if the path is **not** `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in adding the `addResourceLocations`. What you add there is a **file** and not a **location**. The location should be a path, not a file:

```
.addResouceLocations("classpath:/static/")
```

A, maybe better, way to achieve this (with less control) is by adding the static path to the *application.properties* file, like so:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:classpath:/static
```